# Relations between the eigenvalues of a matrix and irreducibility of the characteristic polynomial of its powers

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory

Let $A$ be a square matrix and suppose its characteristic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, I'm trying to understand when are the powers of $A$ also irreducible.

The characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $A^k$ are nicely related: If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$, then the characteristic polynomial of $A^k$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i^k)$. So, can we characterize the irreducibility of the characteristic polynomial of $A^k$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ it means that $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, but this does not mean that $\lambda_i^k$ are irrational too. Let the characteristic  polynomial of $A$ be $x^2-2$. Its eigenvalues are $\pm\sqrt 2$ and the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $2,2$ and the characteristic polynomial is $x^2-4 x+4 = (x-2)^2$

Comment: @Raffaele: well, $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, so if $\lambda_i^k\in\mathbb{Q}$ then the characteristic polynomial of $A^k$ is reducible, but can we say more than that?